# 关于荷爾德林的希波淋的一本中文版本

Tags: translation, culture, books, literature

I found out on Baike Baidu (cf. [here](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%BC%97%E9%87%8C%E5%BE%B7%E9%87%8C%E5%B8%8C%C2%B7%E8%8D%B7%E5%B0%94%E5%BE%B7%E6%9E%97/15096102)) that the novel Hyperion by Hölderlin is translated to 希波淋 where the author has the transcription 荷爾德林.

On the other hand, many questions are left open and I don't find the relevant information on google even if I type Chinese.

1. Was this novel ever translated into Chinese?
2. If so, what is the subtitle "oder der Eremit in Griechenland" translated to?
3. I'm particularly interested in the translation of one sentence out of this novel. Namely, the sentence: "...das ist ein sonderbarer Bettler? seinen letzten Pfenning wirft er in den Sumpf!" [on this page](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/hoelderl/hyperion/hyper108.html). (Note that according to modern writing rules, to my knowledge, the word "Pfenning" is written "Pfennig" in standard German nowadays.)

Of course, I could use google translate or deepL to translate these sentences. But, honestly, the software cannot provide an adequate translation as there are always many words in Chinese to translate one word in German. It also cannot take into account that the novel was published 1799 - and what I want to achieve with my translation is some sort of anachronistic style, i.e. a translation with words out of this century. Except this, the translation software cannot take into account the context of the whole book. And if there is an official translation by an expert, all this is useless anyway, because I would rather prefer a quotation than a translation.

Comment: I can delete the question if you give me a yes or no answer in the comments. I will ask a friend then for a translation of the relevant passages.

Comment: 建议不要看中文版，最好直接看原版的，我知道的好多外文书的中文版都是删减版的。

Comment: @Tom 我不看中文版本，只是用一些引用句写书法，谢谢你的建议，我在中文版本找到一句引用是足够的

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title your looking for is:

> 《许佩里翁或希腊的隐士》

This is equivalent to the full title, "Hyperion oder Der Eremit in Griechenland."

---

There is a published translation that can be found within:

> [image]

and here is a shot of the table of contents for reference:

> [image]

---

Found on p. 35 of this book is the following excerpt:

> [image]

and the translation you were looking for:

> 这是个奇特的乞丐？把最后枚硬币扔进沼泽

Which should match up with, "...das ist ein sonderbarer Bettler? seinen letzten Pfenning wirft er in den Sumpf!"

---

This is a published translation by Hui Dai ([戴晖](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%88%B4%E6%99%96/20432570)). Published by Commercial Press, 2003, Beijing.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for digging this up! I find it very interesting that this book was translated to the Chinese - and only recently in 2003. I myself was finding nothing online. Is this book available to you in its entity? For my calligraphic works, I would like to look up two more passages. Can I do it on my own?

Comment: Concerning the title 许佩里翁或希腊的隐士 one further question: Does it mean that my original transliteration of Hyperion was wrong or is not used in this translation of Hui Dai?

Comment: Also the author has a different transliteration, as I noticed now

Comment: @Christoph Not sure where you got 希波淋 from, I'm not seeing any references to it online. “荷尔德林” is simplified Chinese “荷爾德林” is traditional Chinese. The book can be downloaded from Baidu Yunpan here: https://pan.baidu.com/s/1b44zt

Answer (score 1):

Well, Pfennig is Pfennig, (und wer den Pfennig nicht ehrt ist des Geldes wert!) but how words were and are spelled changes over time. Chinese characters also change with time. Spelling mistakes and dialects happen!

Wilhelm and Jacob Grimm, 200 years after it was introduced, refused to spell nouns with a capital letter!

1. Was this novel ever translated into Chinese? Dunno!

Falls, dann etwa so:

2. oder der Eremit in Griechenland
   or the hermit in Greece
   或者一位住在希腊的隐士
3. Nicht wahr, Alabanda, rief ich ihm zu, das ist ein sonderbarer Bettler?
   Forsooth, Alabanda, I called out to him, that is a strange beggar.
   确实阿拉班达我对他喊道，那是一个奇怪的乞丐。
   Seinen letzten Pfenning wirft er in den Sumpf!
   He threw his last penny in the swamp.
   他把最后一分钱扔进了沼泽地。

Alle Übersetzungen sind vom Übersetzungsministerium zugelassen.
All translations have been approved by the Ministry of Official Translations.
所有翻译都已获得官方翻译部的批准。